# Formating String for a serial number type

Tags: vb.net, format, string-formatting

I wish to format a `string` for display as a serial number e.g.

```
abc12345d67890
```

to

```
00ab-c123-45d6-7890
```

if it was numbers i could

```
DataGridView.Columns(2).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "0000-0000-0000-0000"
MaskedTextBox1.Mask = ("0000-0000-0000-0000")
```

but if it is a `String` this doesn't work. Can anyone help me in a direction?

1. The information is displayed in 16 char for easy reading and understanding some values are 2AFHY89 and **must** be recorded as such
2. It is displayed several different ways/times e.g. label, Textbox, DataGridView,
3. I don't understand IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter so if the value did not have [a-z] i could just use the above example("`0000-0000-0000-0000`")
4. I wish to use a format NOT alter the data stored both examples are not a format just editing the stored data.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question, but would a GUID suit your needs better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pad the serial number with zeros to get the full 16 characters, then split it into 4 character parts and then join the parts with "-" between them.

```
Dim serial As String = "abc12345d67890"
serial = serial.PadLeft(16, "0"c)
Dim parts(3) As String
parts(3) = serial.Substring(serial.Length - 3)
parts(2) = serial.Substring(serial.Length - 7, 4)
parts(1) = serial.Substring(serial.Length - 11, 4)
parts(0) = serial.Substring(0, serial.Length - 12)
Dim formattedSerial As String = String.Join("-", parts)
```

Comment: I was hoping not to edit the value just change the way it was displayed but thanks i will do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want "00" on the front, just add it, even if temporarily in a function.  If it is meant to be some sort of padding, add that to the procedure when the length requires it (question is not clear if it is indeed, left padding).

```
Shared Function FormatSerial(fmt As String, ser As String) As String

    Dim serial As String
    'ToDo: pad L or R as desired, or 
    ' throw an exception when the length is not as expected.
    serial = ("000000000000000").Substring(0, 16 - ser.Length) & ser

    Select Case fmt.ToUpper
        Case "S"
            Return String.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}-{3}", serial.Substring(0, 4),
                      serial.Substring(4, 4), serial.Substring(8, 4),
                      serial.Substring(12, 4))
        Case Else
            Throw New FormatException(
                    String.Format("The '{0}' format specifier is not supported.", fmt))
    End Select


End Function
```

Usage:

```
thatTextBox.Text = FormatSerial("S","abc12345d67890")
Console.WriteLine(FormatSerial("S", strSerial))
```

Output:

> 00ab-c123-45d6-7890

This acts like an `IFormatProvider` but in the form of a Shared function. In other cases, an actual `IFormatProvider` might be better.

#### Notes

1. It is a bit odd for any sort of formatter to add characters as in the padding function.  Generally, formatting just controls how a string is displayed.  If the serial is supposed to display as 16 characters, it probably ought to *have* 16 characters.
2. You can easily add new formats such as an `"R"` format for Raw where the dashes are omitted.

Comment: yes it would be left padding. The idea is that I would use the answer a lot. The value stored would only be "abc12345d67890" 'a string' and the answer would be displayed in several ways eg textbox datagrid

Comment: I have edited the question to hopefully make it easier to understand. Thank for your help.

Comment: Is the DGV databound?  You might see if you can use the CellFormatting event to display it as desired.  In the Edit, would `2AFHY89` have 9 leading zeros?

Comment: yes it is can you give an example i will try latter as it is now 1:42 am